# SQL query returning values not existing in table from set in (brackets)

Tags: sql, t-sql

Need to get values which are not in table, enumerated right in TSQL query

Table Cities

`create table Cities (Id int, City nvarchar (max))
insert into Cities values 
(1, 'New York'),
(2, 'Moscow'),
(3, 'Mexico'),
(4, 'Kuala-Lampur')`

Now I need to extract cities that exist in set 
('Los Angeles', 'Moscow', 'Oslo') but not exist in Cities table.
So I need result:

- Los Angeles
- Olso

I know the easiest way is to use temp table like

```
declare @temp table (City nvarchar (max))
insert into @temp values
(Los Angeles),
(Moscow),
(Oslo)

Select City from @temp
where City not in (Select City from Cities)
```

But may be there is a way to avoid temp table?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a derived table filled with `VALUES`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM (VALUES ('Los Angeles'),
                    ('Moscow'),
                    ('Oslo')) given_cities (city)

       WHERE given_cities.city NOT IN (SELECT cities.city
                                              FROM cities);
```